Power BI Creating Custom Tables from Measures
Good afternoon smart people!
I have created a matrix table in power BI of the data points in the red box in the attached image. The data points are measures calculated from a physical table. My boss wants me to keep the same table format but annualize the 2024 Quantity amount plus add a new row that calculates the compound annual growth rate (CAGR) for the columns from 2019 - the annualized 2024 amounts. The table is also connected to a slicer that updates the amounts based on a region so ideally the new measures would also update. I don't know if it's possible to create a calculation from a visual data point. For example, reference the 700 in 2024 Quantity and do the math off that. Or is there another PBI trick or method to do this? I've been researching more about virtual tables but unsure if that's what I need. Any help is greatly appreciated!


it's better to provide some sample data , not the matrix and the expected output based on the sample data you provided.
